# add an option programatically when adding to cart

Tags: checkout, cart, custom-options

I've to build a shop in which the user chooses a variable number of images to be printed on a product that also has options like format, margin style, material, ...

The images come with license fees that need to be added to the total prize and with an uri that identifies the selected image.

I thought to create an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option` on the fly and adding it via `$product->addOption($option)` before adding the `$product` to the cart. The test looks a bit like:

```
    $product = $this->loadProductFromDb($productId);
    $option = $this->testAddCustomOptionDynamically($productId, $product);
    $product->addOption($option);

    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $cart->addProduct($product, array('options' => array(4200 => 'testvalueselected'), 'selections' => array() ));
    $cart->save();

    $return = array();
    $return['redirect'] = Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart', array('_secure'=>true));
    $return['error'] = false;
    echo json_encode($return);

function testAddCustomOptionDynamically($productId, $product) {
    $product->setHasOptions(1);

    $values = array(
            array(
                    'title'     => 'My custom license',
                    'price'     => 42,
                    'price_type'    => 'fixed'
            )
    );

    $data = array(
            'option_id' => 4200,
            'type'      => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_AREA,
            'is_require'    => 1,
            'price'     => 0,
            'price_type'    => 'fixed',
            'product_id'    => (int)$productId,
            'title'         => 'license option',
            'values'        => $values
    );

    return Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->setData($data)->setProduct($product);
}
```

My problems/questions are:

- Is this a sane approach?
- I still need to test whether the added option influences the products total price.
- The option is not shown in the cart but it should be.

I already saw that the some option information ends up in the table sales_flat_quote_item_option.